# How to check if feature (JSON) exists, and/or version

Tags: mysql

This is a cross-posting from an original question at [How to check version is greater than some base value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675956/how-to-check-version-is-greater-than-some-base-value)

When calling MySQL `SELECT @@VERSION;` or `SELECT VERSION();`, I get for instance '5.7.11-log'. Is there a "well-known" way to check if the version is greater (or smaller) than some major.minor.patch version? If not a well-known way, is there a way without using a temporary table or a user-defined function (there probably is, but for a reason or another currently eludes me)? I would use this to check if there's support for JSON type type that was introduced in version 5.7.8.

Upon researching this more, it appears this is a bit tougher nut for my skills to crack. For instance, I could write something like

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(@@VERSION, '.', 1) AS major, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@@VERSION,'.', 2), '.', -1) AS minor, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@@VERSION,'.', -2), '.', -1) AS patch;
```

but that isn't entirely satisfactory (e.g. see `-log`) and it doesn't directly check the existence of the feature.

Is anyone aware of better ways?

<edit: To amend Rick's answer a bit, the comments syntax can be used to recognize constructs too, not just versions. For instance, in this particular case like this `SELECT /*!JSON_TYPE*/('["a", "b", 1]');`. Here's a link to the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/*!50700 ... */` says:  If you are running a version older than 5.7.0, this is a comment.  Else it is sql.  It can be entire statements or fragments of statements.

Example (taken from `mysqldump` output):

```
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
```

Presumably, `@@TIME_ZONE` was implemented in 4.1.3.

(Note:  I think the two spaces are part of the syntax.)

Comment: This is exactly what the doctor has ordered! Cheers!